# Alternative nested for loops for counting value occurrence in R dataframe

Tags: r

I am working on a large dataset, i what to count how many time two columns have the same values. Here is an example of the dataset:

```
id = rep(replicate(4, paste(sample(LETTERS, 3, replace=F), collapse="")), 12500)
names = rep(replicate(3125, paste(sample(letters, 5, replace=T), collapse="")), 16)
times = sample(c(3,6,24), 50000, replace = T)

df = data.frame(id=id, names=names, times=times)

count <- list()
ids <- as.vector(unique(df$id))
nms <- as.vector(unique(df$names))

for(i in 1:length(ids)){
  vec <- c()
  for(j in 1:length(nms)){
    vec[j] <- nrow(df[df$id == ids[i] & df$names == nms[j], ])
  }
  count[[i]] <- vec
}
```

My real data have about `50000 x 10` dimension and the id and name fields are randomly scattered. Can anyone suggest a better way to handle this? because my approach is working but too slow. `dplyr` or `plyr` methods?

Thanks,

**EDIT:**

short version of my dataframe:

```
id = rep(replicate(3, paste(sample(LETTERS, 3, replace=F), collapse="")), 5)
names = rep(replicate(3, paste(sample(letters, 5, replace=T), collapse="")), 5)
times = sample(c(3,6,24), 15, replace = T)

df = data.frame(id=id, names=names, times=times)
df
   id names times
1  DEW xxsre    24
2  QHY xkbhr    24
3  DQE tuyfk     6
4  DEW xxsre    24
5  QHY xkbhr    24
6  DQE tuyfk     3
7  DEW xxsre     3
8  QHY xkbhr    24
9  DQE tuyfk     3
10 DEW xxsre    24
11 QHY xkbhr    24
12 DQE tuyfk     3
13 DEW xxsre    24
14 QHY xkbhr     3
15 DQE tuyfk     3
```

output:

```
> count
[[1]]
[1] 5 0 0

[[2]]
[1] 0 5 0

[[3]]
[1] 0 0 5
```

each list item is for id, and the list vec is for names count. in other words `as.vector(unique(df$id))` and `as.vector(unique(df$names))` respectively.

Comment: I don't see how the `id`, `names`, and `times` columns will ever be equal to each other.  Where do you define your _original_ data frame?

Comment: I thought `times` was the column that OP wants to create and just included it in the example as expected output..(?)... Don't know...

Comment: I tried to run it with a smaller size of `df` (500 rows), but the resulting count is just a list of 4, each consists of 125 ones.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i made mention that id and name fields are random

Comment: Just use `sum(df$col1 == df$col2, na.rm=TRUE)`, assuming you have character or numerical columns.

Comment: `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, .(Count = .N), by = list(id, names)]` but this will not give you a list...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data.table`, which is likely the fastest solution:

```
library(data.table)


# convert your dataset into a data.table
  setDT(df)


output <- df [ , .N, by = .(id, names)]


head(output)
>     id names N
> 1: FYG vlrcd 4
> 2: FAL mjhhs 4
> 3: BZU rfnvc 4
> 4: HJA zhssf 4
> 5: FYG pxtne 4
> 6: FAL qgeqr 4
```

If you want the output to be a `list`, you can convert the output in different ways:

```
L1 <- as.list(as.data.frame(t(output)))  # or

L2 <- split(output, list(output$id, output$names))  # or

L3 <- split(output, seq(nrow(output)))
```

Comment: This is the same as my answer in comments which I didn't post as its output is not the same as the OP's...I was expecting to hear from OP if it is acceptable and then post it...

Comment: @Sotos, my apologies, I had not seen your comment. Please go ahead and post your answer.

Comment: That's fine. We can leave yours since it's up :)

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
library(dplyr)
count <- df %>%
  group_by(id, names) %>%
  summarise(n=sum(times))
count
```

Comment: replace `summarise(n=sum(times))` with `summarise(n=n())` to get counts. Not a list however

Answer (score 0):

Without using plyr and dplyr you can reduce computing time by 25%.

To a reasonnable computing time, I subsetted the first 1000 rows of your data.

```
library(microbenchmark)
id = rep(replicate(4, paste(sample(LETTERS, 3, replace=F), collapse="")), 12500)
names = rep(replicate(3125, paste(sample(letters, 5, replace=T), collapse="")), 16)
times = sample(c(3,6,24), 50000, replace = T)

df = data.frame(id=id, names=names, times=times)
df = df[1:1000,]
ids <- as.vector(unique(df$id))
nms <- as.vector(unique(df$names))
```

Then I define 3 functions, default, summation, and sum+preallocation

```
default<-function(ids,nms,df){
  count <- list()

  for(i in 1:length(ids)){
    vec <- c()
    for(j in 1:length(nms)){
      vec[j] <- nrow(df[df$id == ids[i] & df$names == nms[j], ])
    }
    count[[i]] <- vec
  }
}

summation<-function(ids,nms,df){
  count <- list()

  for(i in 1:length(ids)){
    vec <- c()
    for(j in 1:length(nms)){
      vec[j] <- sum(df$id == ids[i] & df$names == nms[j])
    }
    count[[i]] <- vec
  }
}

summation_and_preallocation<-function(ids,nms,df){
  count <- list()

  for(i in 1:length(ids)){
    vec <- integer(length = length(nms))
    for(j in 1:length(nms)){
      vec[j] <- sum(df$id == ids[i] & df$names == nms[j])
    }
    count[[i]] <- vec
  }
}
```

Tests with microbenchmark show:

```
m<-microbenchmark(default(ids,nms,df),summation(ids,nms,df),summation_and_preallocation(ids,nms,df),times = 10)
Unit: milliseconds
                                      expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
                     default(ids, nms, df) 994.5040 1012.1560 1040.7012 1042.5689 1072.4689 1074.8893    10
                   summation(ids, nms, df) 735.0831  740.6620  741.2254  742.1361  742.9321  743.7806    10
 summation_and_preallocation(ids, nms, df) 729.1192  733.0536  753.8661  736.8319  791.5001  804.2335    10
```

How does it compare with `dplyr` solution from @Adrian?

```
 dplyr_count(ids, nms, df) 3.154741 3.206819 49.06034 3.275624 3.701375 457.943    10
```

So about 200 times faster for `dplyr`!